# SQL: Группирование записей таблицы, и последующий вывод данных

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица с платежами. Каждый студент может иметь несколько платежей. Это контролируется по полю **id_student**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача: нужно вывести список всех студентов и к каждому присоединить свой список платежей, то есть сделать группирование по **id_student**

Нужно сгрупировать данные в виде следующей таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю так:

```
$sqlPay = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payment GROUP BY id_student ") or  die(mysql_error());
$listPay = mysql_fetch_array($sqlPay);

do{

print"
<tr>
   <td> $listPay[id_student]</td>
   <td> $listPay[id_payment]</td>
   <td> $listPay[amount] </td>
   <td> $listPay[num_pago]</td>                             
 <tr>";             
}

while($listPay = mysql_fetch_array($sqlPay)  );
```

Результат не тот которого ожидаю. Выдает только одну запись с платежом. Нужно все чтоб собирало.
Подскажите как составить запрос.

Comment: Уберите группировку в SQL, добавьте order by по студенту  и решайте чисто на php сравнивая студента из текущей и предыдущей записи.

Answer (score 3):

mysql_query рекомендую выкинуть на помойку и использовать PDO.
GROUP BY здесь тоже, кстати, как коню велосипед.

Пишем

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT p.id_student, * FROM payment p")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

и получаем наши данные уже сгруппированными по студентам. Остается вывести с помощью двух вложенных циклов.

Comment: Eсли не трудно, покажите как это реализовать до конечного результата. Спасибо.

Comment: я же написал. два вложенных друг в друга foreach

Comment: Я понял что с помощью foreach,  только ума не приложу как это все вывести... (( Я с PDO не знаком..

Comment: Никакого пдо здесь и близко нет. Тут простой стандартный пхп массив.